# R ggplot putting annotation in geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have `geom_tile` which I am plotting in polar coordinate. I want to put a grey circle at the centre and my chart title inside that.

**Here is my reproducible implementation**.

```
require(ggplot2)
# Create the data frame.
sales_data <- data.frame(
  emp_name = c("Sam", "Dave", "John", "Harry", "Clark", "Kent", "Kenneth", "Richard", "Clement", "Toby", "Jonathan"), 
  month = as.factor(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Jan")),
  dept_name = as.factor(c("Production", "Services", "Support", "Support", "Services", "Production", "Production", "Support", "Support", "Support", "Production")), 
  revenue = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 500)
)

sales_data$month <- factor(sales_data$month, levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"))


categorical_bubble_chart <- ggplot(data = sales_data, aes(x = month, y = dept_name)) +
  #geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -1, ymax = 0), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.03)+
  #annotate("text", x=0, y=-1, label= "Risk Register", fontface =2) +
  geom_tile(data = expand.grid(sales_data$month, sales_data$dept_name), 
            aes(x = Var1, y = Var2), fill = NA, col = 'gray50', lty = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(size = revenue, col = revenue), 
             shape = 16, position = position_jitter(seed = 0), show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(aes(label = revenue), vjust = 1.6, position = position_jitter(seed = 0)) +

  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -1, ymax = 0), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.03)+
  annotate("text", x=0, y=-1, label= "Chart title", fontface =2) +

  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  ) +
coord_polar()

categorical_bubble_chart
```

And the output:
[image]

If you comment the last line `coord_polar()` to plot it in cartesian coordinate. Here is the output:
[image]

So, basically the grey rectangle should lie right below the bottom tile row so that in polar coordinate it will be shown as circle fitting inside and no break slice.

Please help me or suggest a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to make this work.  First, its easier if you convert your x axis (month) to a numeric rather than a factor.  The we can control the axis more using `scale_x_continuous`.  Having done this, you just need to set the `geom_rect` coordinates to fill the space:

```
sales_data$month <- as.integer(sales_data$month)

ggplot(sales_data, aes(x = month, y = dept_name)) +
  geom_tile(data = expand.grid(sales_data$month, sales_data$dept_name), 
            aes(x = Var1, y = Var2), fill = NA, col = 'gray50', lty = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(size = revenue, col = revenue), 
             shape = 16, position = position_jitter(seed = 0), show.legend = F) +
  geom_text(aes(label = revenue), vjust = 1.6, position = position_jitter(seed = 0)) +

  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 3.5, ymin = -1, ymax = 0.5), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.03)+
  annotate("text", x=0.5, y=-1, label= "Chart title", fontface =2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_blank(), 
    axis.line = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  ) +
  coord_polar(start = 0.5, clip = 'off') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,3.5), expand = c(0,0), breaks = 1:3, labels = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dww. 
Yes, this is what I want. But at the same time, there should be no break in slice. Polar coordinate should be circle and not a split. :-(

Comment: Sorry I thought you were referring to the gap between the grey circle and the chart.  Let me see about the "slice"  probably just need to play wih axis limits

Comment: No need for sorry :-)
It's me who need help and guidance, you are providing selfless help.

BTW, I doubt that with geom_rect this issue can be fixed, I feel that having a blank grey row at the bottom of `geom_tiles` would be better solution.

May be I am wrong.

Comment: Hahaha :)
I must say, you are one hell of R sorcerer !!